# How to import files whose size is greater than some value?

Tags: matlab

I have some data stored in `.csv` files with different file size. I need to import files with size greater than some particular value say 10MB. How can I do that? I am using `xlsread` to import the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dir` to get file information in the directory where files are located

```
threshold = 1000; % set threshold for size

filenames = dir('*.csv');
for i = 1:length(filenames)
  if filenames(i).bytes> threshold
    data=xlsread(filenames(i).name);
    ***your code here
  end
end
```